# How do I implement staggered views in reading order?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

Here is what I want to implement:

[image: Staggered Views]

I'm trying to display definitions I'm getting from the web (right now they're coming from dummy data, but that's neither here nor there).

My first thought was to use a horizontal StaggeredGridView. There are two problems with this. The views are not laid out in the correct order and the span count is not set dynamically. Also, I found out that calling setSpanCount() in onLayoutChildren() causes an error at run time.

[image: Staggered View Attempt]

Of course, I could just have a LinearLayout and forego my attempt to recycle views. That would work in most cases, but if the user did happen upon a length definition, it would be very memory inefficient.

With that in mind, I resolved to subclass StaggeredGridLayoutManager. And this is where I need your help. Here are the resources I found in my own search:

[Google's Implementation of a LinearLayoutManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/0b1059b/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java)

[A Guide Implementing a Custom LayoutManager](https://developer.inthepocket.mobi/2017/01/04/android-layoutmanager-part-1/)

[Another Guide for Implementing a Custom LayoutManager](https://medium.com/@v.danylo/10-steps-to-create-a-custom-layoutmanager-2f30ab2f979d)

[An Overview of a Few Principles to Follow when Implementing a Custom LayoutManager](https://www.azoft.com/blog/layoutmanager-android/)

I went through each one of these, but I cannot mentally separate out what parts are there for their specific use-cases and what parts are common to all custom implementations. If someone could be so kind as to point me in the direction of a resource or explain what all the methods I have to call in what order and for what purpose, I would be immensely grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first screenshot looks like a perfect case for [Google's FlexboxLayout library](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). You can use the [FlexboxLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview) with RecyclerView to get exactly what you showed.